# Polymorphic Routes in Rails 4.1.4

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a polymorphic association between Posts and Postables, right now with Projects being my only Postables. In my routes, I have:

```
resources :projects do
  ...

  member do
    resources :posts
  end
end
```

I know how to retrieve the right ids from the parameters, and all of my controller specs pass just fine, but when I try to write links in my views, they don't work. Running `rake routes`, I see a little weirdness:

```
...

post SHOW      /projects/:id/posts/:id(.:format)    posts#edit

...
```

And so on for the rest. If I'm not mistaken, the path should be 'new_project_post', and the first parameter should be `:project_id`.

Now, in my `show` view for Projects, I have the index of posts for that particular project. But the links don't work. Lets assume I have a project with an ID of 2, and a post for that project with an ID of 1.

If I try `link_to 'Edit', edit_post_path(@project, post)`, the link comes out as `.../projects/1/posts/1/edit`, so both `:id`s get the post's id. If I swap `post` and `@project`, both `:id`s will be the project's id.

If I try passing them as an array, `link_to 'Edit', post_path([post, @project])`, the resulting link will be `.../projects/1%2F2/posts/1%2F2/edit`. `%2F` is a URL-encoded slash character, so I'm not sure what the hell Rails is trying to do here.

If I try using `polymorphic_path([@project, post])` for my links, all it does is spit out paths that don't exist: `undefined method 'project_post_path'`

I've tried several other combinations of parameters without success. So if anyone could point me in the right direction, I'd be extremely grateful.

Comment: Because I'm an idiot and forgot to remove the member block when I moved posting to its own controller. And that solved it, so thank you. Post that and I'll mark it as the answer. God, I need to get more sleep.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The appropriate syntax for nested resources in Rails is:

```
resources :projects do
  resources :posts
end
```

In `member` block you could only declare additional actions to work with project instances.

Answer (score -1):

You are using nested resource inside `member` and it is incorrect. Read more about this here: http://thelazylog.com/posts/polymorphic-routes-in-rails